# How to get VM VID partition of Running VM's only

Tags: powershell, hyper-v, perfmon

A simple syntax question please. I am not getting it right. Please help:

This lists the VM VID for both Running and Paused VM's

```
Get-Counter '\Hyper-V VM VID Partition(*)\*'
```

This lists all the running VM's:

```
$g = Get-VM | Where-Object {$_.State -eq 'Running'} | Select-Object -Property Name
```

My guess is something like `Get-Counter '\Hyper-V $g VID Partition(*)\*'` might work but am not getting the syntax right. 
How can I combine the two and get the VM VID for Running VM's only please?

Comment: I have no idea if the command you are trying will work or not, but because you surround it with single quotes (`'`), the variable `$g` will not get expanded. Try it with double quotes (`"`)

Comment: The two commands I give independently works perfectly. The problem is "Hyper-V VM VID Partition(*)" is a Perfmon Counter name and I don't know if I can break the counter name or not.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may need to use `ForEach-Object`. Something like:

```
$g = Get-VM | Where-Object {$_.State -eq 'Running'} | 
     ForEach-Object { Get-Counter -ComputerName $_.Name -Counter '\Hyper-V VM VID Partition(*)\*'}
```

Cannot try this myself..

Comment: Thanks @Theo  

Get-VM | Where-Object {$_.State -eq 'Running'} | ForEach-Object { Get-Counter -Counter '\Hyper-V VM VID Partition(*)\*'}  

I had 3 paused VMs and 2 running VMs what this command did was print 3 times both the paused and running VM's VID. Get-Counter does not support specifying individual VM's. What needs to happen is do Get-Counter first and then pipe it to something one object at a time that will filter out all the paused VM's. That is the trick I am unable to fathom.

Comment: @SantoshKumar ..but there you left out the `-ComputerName` parameter on `Get-Counter`..

Comment: I am running it on my local system hence I don't need it. I have a local system with Hyper-V enabled and 5 VM's on it. So your command runs fine. There is small typo in my above comment. I have 2 paused and 3 running. Also sorry the format is wrong. If nothing work I will manually filter the Paused VM's out :(. BTW my format is all messed up sorry. CTRL-K did not work for me nor the putting 2 spaces at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I have finally realized there is no way to do this in a single command. So this is how I solved it:

```
pPipe1 = _wpopen(L"powershell -Command \"Get-Counter '\\Hyper-V VM VID Partition(*)\\*'\"", L"rt")
```

This will get me the full list of all Running and Paused VM socketID. Then I do list of Paused VM's.

```
pPipe2 = _wpopen(L"powershell -Command \"Get-VM | Where-Object {$_.State -eq 'Paused'};\" ",  L"rt" )
```

Using both the pipe I filter out the Paused and I have the list of Running VM's with their socket ID.